# docker-compose unable to connect to container in build process

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try i setup a Shopware Docker Container for development. I setup a Dockerfile for the Shopware initialize process but every time i run the build process shopware return this error message:

> mysql -u 'root' -p'root' -h 'dbs' --port='3306' -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `shopware6dev`"
>           ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'dbs' (-2)

i think docker setup the default network after all build processes are done but i need to connect before all containers are ready. The depends_on option brings nothing. I hope anyone have a idea to solve this problem.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
shopwaredev:
    build:
        context: ./docker/web
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./log:/var/log/apache2
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=shopware6dev.test,www.shopware6dev.test
        - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect
    restart: on-failure:10
    depends_on:
        - dbs
adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: on-failure:10
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
dbs:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    volumes:
        - ./mysql57:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=shopware6dev
    restart: on-failure:10
nginx-proxy:
    image: solution360/nginx-proxy
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/certs
    restart: on-failure:10
```

and this is my dockerfile for web shopwaredev container:

```
FROM solution360/apache24-php74-shopware6
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN rm index.html

RUN git clone https://github.com/shopware/development.git .

RUN cp .psh.yaml.dist .psh.yaml

RUN sed -i 's|DB_USER: "app"|DB_USER: "root"|g' .psh.yaml
RUN sed -i 's|DB_PASSWORD: "app"|DB_PASSWORD: "root"|g' .psh.yaml
RUN sed -i 's|DB_HOST: "mysql"|DB_HOST: "dbs"|g' .psh.yaml
RUN sed -i 's|DB_NAME: "shopware"|DB_NAME: "shopware6dev"|g' .psh.yaml
RUN sed -i 's|APP_URL: "http://localhost:8000"|APP_URL: "http://shopware6dev.test"|g' .psh.yaml

RUN ./psh.phar install
```

Comment: Don't you need a tab below services in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: yeah, its formatting from stackoverflow

Comment: It seems in 'dbs' you haven't done a port binding 3306:3306

Comment: but if i run the install command after all containers are up it worked

Comment: It seems you need to use wait for it https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: can you write a example for the case i posted ?

Comment: How about moving all the database initialization to a sql script and run the script when the DB image is initialized instead ? The MySQL image exposes the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory and any sql script file placed in there will be automatically be executed on DB initialization. See the docker-compose file in this repo for an example: https://bitbucket.org/Bolbeck/mkecodecampnodemysql/src/master/

Comment: nice idea but the creation of the database and its data is not the problem. the connection is the problem. and i cant create a sql script for initialization, shopware install all DB data in its installation process